# How to open html5 input type="file" automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to open **input type="file"** dialog automatically in **useEffect** hook.But it sometimes works and sometimes are not.What can be a problem?

This is my input

```
<input
  id="loadFromPc"
  type="file"
  accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
  onChange={e => loadFile(e)}
/>
```

and this is my hook

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const { search } = window.location;
    if (search && queryString.parse(search).userSelect === 'upload_photo') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('[setTimeout]');
        document.getElementById('loadFromPc').click();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: perhaps `search && queryString.parse(search).userSelect === 'upload_photo'` is false - why do you need a setTimeout? does it work more often is setTimeout is LONGER?

Comment: Sometimes works sometimes not. You are accepting only file of extension 'jpeg and  png'. So, if you are uploading other extension files, it would not work.

Comment: `console.log('[setTimeout]')` this part always working!!!.The problem is click() event.I added setTimeout to ensure that my DOM fully ready. Because my component renders many times.It takes some props. `If mention sometimes working sometimes not i mean opening dialog, not extensions]`

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is related to multiple rendering, you can modify the hook condition:

```
if (search && queryString.parse(search).userSelect === 'upload_photo' && document.getElementById('loadFromPc')) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('[setTimeout]');
        document.getElementById('loadFromPc').click();
      }, 1000);
```

and add the checking of the element if it has already fully loaded before firing the click.

Also try checking the [Hooks FAQ page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) and the [React Effect Hook Introduction page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) or the [Rules of Hooks in the React Documents page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: **console.log('[setTimeout]')** this part always working!!!.The problem is click() event.I added **setTimeout** to ensure that my DOM fully ready. Because my component renders many times.It takes some props.

Comment: when it doesn't work does it have an error? If so, please add that to the question. I assumed that the click part was never executed when you said 'sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: Don't.I don't getting any Error!!! I also do this `console.log(document.getElementById('loadFromPc'))` and it gives me my input. Always.

Comment: Are you able to show the code for `loadFile` function? Does it contain `e.preventDefault()` function call?

Answer (score 0):

Its my **loadFile** function.

```
  function loadFile(e) {
    removePopup({
      name: 'image_picker'
    });

    const ff = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
      const image = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

      addLayer(image, image_index, export_size, 'photos', tariff !== null);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(ff);
  }
```

And i don't have any problem about file loading.It's works fine